# How to keep the scroll position of div stable on load content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div (**inbox-chat**) which contains data retrieved from database using ajax. the content is refreched every 5 seconds.
the div have a scroll bar. the problem here is when the div is refreshed to load new data, the scroll bar goes to top, and then the user cannot read what is written on the bottom of the div content.

the content is loaded here

**messages.php**

```
<div id="inbox">
    <img src="assets/images/loaders/preload.gif" class="loading_inbox" >
</div>
```

here is an example of **HTML** code

**ajax/inbox.php** (EIDTED)

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
    require_once '../../config/connect.php';
    require_once '../../functions/func.php'; 

$uid   = $_GET['sender_id'];
$uid  = get_username_id($_GET['sender_id']);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `forum_inbox` 
                                WHERE 
                                (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
                                OR 
                                (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
                                ORDER BY dateMsg DESC");

$stmt->execute(array($uid, $_SESSION['id_userf'], $_SESSION['id_userf'], $uid));    
$messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 ?>

 <?php if($stmt->rowCount() != 0): // STARTS CHECK IF ANY RECORDS EXISTS IN INBOX TABLE ?>
<div id="inbox-chat">
    <section class="chat-container">
        <ol class="chat-box">
            <div class="new-msg"></div>
            <?php 
                foreach($messages AS $msg): 

                    if(get_username($msg->sender_id) == $_SESSION['usernamef']){
                        $direction = 'another';
                    }else{
                        $direction = 'me';
                    }
             ?> 
                <li class="<?php echo $direction ?>">

                    <div class="avatar-icon">
                        <a title="Voir profil de <?php echo get_username($msg->sender_id); ?>" href="profil.php?user=<?php echo get_username($msg->sender_id) ?>&pane=profile">
                        <img src="assets/images/profiles/<?php echo get_user_profile_pic($msg->sender_id)?>">
                        </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="messages">
                        <p><?php echo $msg->message ?></p>
                        <time datetime="<?php echo convert_date_format_full(convert_timestamp($msg->dateMsg));?>">
                            <?php echo time_stamp($msg->dateMsg);?>
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo convert_date_format_full(convert_timestamp($msg->dateMsg)); ?>
                        </time>
                    </div>
                </li>               
            <?php endforeach; ?>          
          </ol>
    </section>
</div>
 <?php else: ?>    
    <div class="panel-body" style="width:50%; margin:5px auto;text-align:center;">
        <div class="media v-middle">
            <h2>Pas de message</h2>
           <img src="assets/images/no-msg.png">
        </div>
    </div> 
 <?php endif; // ENDS CHECK IF ANY RECORDS EXISTS IN INBOX TABLE ?>
```

**js file** (inbox.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sender_id = $(".u").val(); 
    var $container = $("#inbox");
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/inbox.php',
        data : 'sender_id='+sender_id,  
        before : function(){
            $(".loading_inbox").show();
        },
        success : function(data){   
            $(".loading_inbox").hide();
            $("#inbox").html(data);
        }
    });

    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.load('ajax/inbox.php?sender_id='+sender_id);
    }, 10000);  
});
```

Im using this css for the **inbox-chat** class

```
#inbox-chat  .chat-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;    
    height: 450px;    
    background-color: #FAFCFB;

}

#inbox-chat  .chat-box {
    list-style: none;
    background: #fdfdfd;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;

}

#inbox-chat  .chat-box li {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

#inbox-chat  .chat-box .avatar-icon {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#inbox-chat  .chat-box .avatar-icon img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

#inbox-chat  .me {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#inbox-chat  .me .messages {
    order: 1;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }

#inbox-chat  .me .avatar-icon {
    order: 2;
}
#inbox-chat  .messages {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;    
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #c9cccd;
    color:#424242;
}

#inbox-chat  .messages p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
}

#inbox-chat  .messages time {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Take a look at the div from here

http://jsfiddle.net/devstar/rgjfqsb2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're replacing the entire content of your inbox element with `$("#inbox").html(data);`.

Before replacing, save the scroll position with `var scroll=$("#inbox")[0].scrollTop;` and after replacing, restore it with `$("#inbox")[0].scrollTop=scroll;`.

I don't know if you're ajaxing the entire message history or only maybe the 10 newest and if newer messages are at the end or at the beginning - but you may need to calculate heights of the new elements and add/substract it to/from the scroll value.

---

**Edit:**

Btw, why are you ajaxing all the messages every 5 seconds, and not just the new ones and `append` or `prepend` them next to the existing messages? This would eliminate the need for storing and restoring the scroll position.

Add message id to each of your messages and a class to select them with:

```
            <li class="message me" data-messageid="65">
                <div class="avatar-icon">                       
                    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/user1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="messages">
                        <p>Hi buddy !</p>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Then select the newest message and send that to your php handler:

```
var sender_id = $(".u").val(); 
var newest_msg=$(".message:last").data("messageid");
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax/inbox.php',
    data : {
        sender_id: sender_id,
        newest_msg: newest_msg
    },
    success : function(data){   
        $("#inbox").append(data); //append it, not replace
    }
});
```

And in your PHP:

```
$uid  = $_GET['sender_id'];
$uid  = get_username_id($_GET['sender_id']);
$newest_msg = $_GET['newest_msg'];
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `forum_inbox` 
    WHERE 
        (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
    OR 
        (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
    AND 
        message_id > {$newest_msg}
    ORDER BY dateMsg DESC
");
```

Notice I select only messages with id's greater than the newest message.

Comment: I've edited the ajax/inbox.php
How to do it? any suggestion please,?

Comment: Thanks @Oksanen but I think I need to refresh the div to get the newest messages of other users ! I don't see the setinterval function here!

Comment: I'm obviously not going to code the entire thing for you - that's not what Stackoverflow is for. I just wrote the most important parts so you would get the basic idea of how it could be done. From there you'd be able to figure out the rest, like intervals which you had already done right. I don't know  what you mean by messages of other users (you didn't go into much detail on how your app works) or how your database is structured, but with a few alterations to your sql query you should be able to pull off what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load('ajax/inbox.php?sender_id='+sender_id);
    $(".chat-box").css("height", "auto");
    var height = $(".chat-box").height();
    $(".chat-box").css("height", 450);
    $(".chat-box").scrollTop(height);
```

}, 10000);

replace this function.

Comment: Thanks for help, but using the code you provide me the scroll bar goes to the bottom and then goes back to the top when the div is refreshed, how to keep it always in its position?